# Lookup failure when linking using -rpath and $ORIGIN

Tags: gcc, linker, shared, rpath

I'm trying to learn how to use the `-rpath` option in GCC's linker (ld) with `$ORIGIN`.

I'm trying the simplest example I can think of (see below), and all the links I read seem to say I'm doing it correctly.

However, when I run the executable it can't find the shared object unless I run it from within `$ORIGIN`.

Using readelf -d on the executable (main.run) shows:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [lib/foo.so]
...
0x000000000000000f (RPATH) Library rpath: [$ORIGIN]
...
```

The file structure (relevant files) is:

- `/make/test/dll_test/`

  - `main.run`
  - `lib/`

    - `foo.so`

Executing from within dll_test works fine.
Executing from elsewhere (/make/test) gives the error:

> dll_test/main.run: error while loading
>   shared libraries: lib/foo.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

I'm using `-l:foo.so` instead of `-lfoo`, but this shouldn't affect anything (I hope).

---

## SOURCE FILES

### `dll_test/src/foo.cpp`

```
int foo()
    { return 1; }
```

### `dll_test/src/main.cpp`

```
int foo();

#include <iostream>


int main()
  {
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
  }
```

## BUILD SCRIPT

### `dll_test/make.sh`

```
mkdir -p -v obj
mkdir -p -v lib

g++ -c -o obj/foo.o src/foo.cpp -fPIC
g++ -shared -o lib/foo.so obj/foo.o

g++ -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -o main.run obj/main.o -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' -Llib -l:foo.so
```

To build, create these files in their respective locations and simply run "sh make.sh" from within dll_test (or wherever the project root is).
It should generate "dll_test/main.run".

Running "main.run" from within dll_test should work (prints 1).
Running "main.run" from within dll_test fails. Why?

Also, foo.so's path stored in main.run as [lib/foo.so]. Can I get it to be [foo.so] so I can use the -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib' ?

Comment: Apologies for the editing before. NoScript hid the preview and I assumed I was writing raw text.

Comment: As this question is a bit confusing, I rewrote it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311016/building-a-simple-hello-world-esque-example-of-using-lds-option-rpath-with-o

Answer (score 0):

You need `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib'` instead of just `'$ORIGIN'`.

edit: Are you actually entering `-l:foo.so`?  That seems odd... you should be just fine with `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib' -Llib -lfoo.so`.  If that doesn't work, add `-Wl,-soname,libfoo.so` to the linker command for your shared library.  I'm not positive that this will fix the "lib/foo.so" issue, but it's worth a shot :)

Comment: The `-l:foo.so` is accurate. I'm trying to avoid using the `lib` prefix in my code as it's superfluous, linux-specific and IMO harder to read.

Comment: Tried all combinations of `$ORIGIN/lib`, `$ORIGIN`, `-Llib` vs no -L. No luck. Tried `-lfoo.so` and `-soname`, no luck there either.