# ld: Using -rpath,$ORIGIN inside a shared library (recursive)

Tags: linux, linker, shared, rpath

I just made a basic example of using ld's `-rpath` option with `$ORIGIN` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311016/building-a-simple-hello-world-esque-example-of-using-lds-option-rpath-with-o) (see 2nd response for a working version). I'm trying to create an example where `main.run` links to `foo.so`, which in turn links to `bar.so`, all using `rpath` and `$ORIGIN`.

The run-time file-structure is:

> - project/
>
>   - lib/
>
>     - dir/
>
>       - sub/
>
>         - **bar.so**
>       - **foo.so**
>   - run/
>
>     - **main.run** (failing to build)

I'm building foo.so using:

```
g++ -c -o obj/foo.o src/foo.cpp -fPIC
g++ -shared -o lib/dir/foo.so obj/foo.o -Wl,-soname,foo.so -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/sub' -Llib/dir/sub -l:bar.so
```

Which builds fine. `ldd lib/dir/foo.so` can even find `bar.so`.

However, when I try to link `main.run` to `foo.so`, `foo.so` can't find bar.so.

I'm building main.so using:

```
g++ -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -o run/main.run obj/main.o -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib/dir' -Llib/dir -l:foo.so
```

This works fine if another version of `foo.so` is used that doesn't recursively link. (Uncomment lines in make.sh, in project below, to test).

However, using the normal `foo.so` I'm getting this error when building `main.run`:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: bar.so, needed by lib/dir/foo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

So my questions are:

1. Does `$ORIGIN` within foo.so resolve to `project/lib/dir` (where `foo.so` is) or `project/run` (where `main.run` (the executable linking it) is)?
   ldd would seem to indicate that it's `project/lib/dir`, which would seem to be the best way (although I tried assuming both).
2. How do I get these to link (while preserving relocatability) - preferably without using `-rpath-link`.

You can download the project [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31990648/SourceForge/rpath_origin_recursive/project.zip). It's as simple as I can make it. 4 short sources and a script.
After extracting, just run `./make.sh` from within `project/`.

**Note:** I'm using `-l:`. This shouldn't change anything except that the libraries are named like `foo.so` instead of `libfoo.so`, and lunk with `-l:foo.so` instead of `-lfoo`.

Comment: Try `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib/dir' -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/sub'`.  (Maybe the foo.so rpath is not getting incorporated into the final exe's rpath)

Comment: Actually, I should clarify - the build is failing (when making main.run) so there is no final exe. I'll fix that up.

Comment: No luck on that sorry. Added every path I could think of to both.

Comment: Also note: It builds without error if `foo.so`'s `-rpath` is absolute, not `$ORIGIN`.

Comment: Oh well :-).  If you do not get any useful answers here, try asking on the binutils@sourceware.org mailing list.

Comment: Wait a sec.  Is `$ORIGIN` the same for both links?  (I believe each object, whether .so or executable, can only have one `$ORIGIN`.)  You may have to provide a different -rpath and -rpath-link to build foo.so, so that the `$ORIGIN` in the .so itself refers to the origin of main.run.

Comment: I'm going to write a question to binutils@sourceware.org. I'll post the answer here when I'm done.

Comment: The reason your `$ORIGIN` is not expanding is because you have surrounded it with a single-quote; try a double-quote.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I have something working.  But I do not really understand why it works.  This feels like a bug in ld to me.

I ran `strace -f -o /var/tmp/strace.out -- g++ ...` for the main.run compilation.  The static linker is actually trying to open files whose literal name looks like "$ORIGIN/lib/dir/sub/bar.so", among 20-30 other things.  (In other words, it is looking for an actual directory named `$ORIGIN`.  Seriously.)

It also appears to be searching the -rpath-link path for the name "lib/dir/sub/bar.so", not just "bar.so".  I have no clue why.

Anyway, this is the link for main.run that is working for me:

```
g++ -o run/main.run obj/main.o -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib/dir' -Wl,-rpath-link,. -Llib/dir -l:foo.so
```

It is identical to yours but with `-Wl,-rpath-link,.` inserted.

[addendum]

OK I think I see what is going on.  First, the static linker (GNU ld) simply does not honor $ORIGIN in the libraries it links against.

Second, the behavior when you use `-lbar` versus `-l:bar.so` is very different.

Run `readelf -a` on `foo.so`.  In your build, it shows a dependency on "lib/dir/sub/bar.so". This is why setting the rpath-link to "." fixes the build of main.run; it causes the static linker to search "." for "lib/dir/sub/bar.so", which it finds.

If you rename bar.so to libbar.so, and link foo.so to use `-lbar` instead of `-l:bar.so`, the same readelf shows that foo.so now depends on "libbar.so" (with no path component).  With that foo.so, you can get the main.run link to work using `-Wl,-rpath-link,lib/dir/sub`, as you would expect if you knew that the static linker simply does not honor $ORIGIN.

By the way, I do not see the `-l:bar.so` syntax documented anywhere in the GNU ld manual.  Out of curiosity, how did you come up with it?

Assuming it is a supported feature, this looks a bit like a bug (-l:bar.so creating a dependency on lib/dir/sub/bar.so instead of just bar.so).  You can either deal with this bug by setting rpath-link to '.' for main.run, or you can rename stuff in the usual way (libxxx.so).

Comment: I did try that, no luck. That's what question #1 was about. ld's documentation doesn't mention $ORIGIN so I'm not sure where to look for the official stuff.

Comment: Damn, that doesn't work here. I tried strace (ty), and the only open commands containing bar are `./bar.so`, ones with `$ORIGIN`, ones in `/usr`, `//lib/bar.so`.... As for `-l:`, I remember searching for how to not use the `lib` prefix, or to use complete filenames - but I can't find the link now. I'll keep looking.

Comment: My `readelf -a foo.so` doesn't show `lib/dir/sub/bar.so` in my original build, just `bar.so`. Perhaps our systems are different. (Core2 duo, Ubuntu 64 10.04, ld = 2.20.51-system.20100908, gcc 4.4.5(Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)) - This is all default, I haven't touched them.

Comment: If your readelf shows "bar.so" as the dependency, then "-Wl,-rpath-link,lib/dir/sub" should allow main.run to link.  What does strace show if you inlcude lib/dir/sub in rpath-link while building main.run?

Comment: A bit late on the boat - I'm suffering the same problem as the OP was - but thought I'd add that `man ld` does document the `-l:bar.so` syntax quite well.. Under `-l namespec` :-

```If namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a.```

Answer (score 7):

From the [ld-linux(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) manpage:

> $ORIGIN and rpath
>
> ld.so understands the string $ORIGIN (or equivalently ${ORIGIN}) in an
>   rpath specification (DT_RPATH or DT_RUNPATH) to mean the directory
>   containing the application executable. Thus, an application located in
>   somedir/app could be compiled with gcc -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib' so
>   that it finds an associated shared library in somedir/lib no matter
>   where somedir is located in the directory hierarchy. This facilitates
>   the creation of "turn-key" applications that do not need to be
>   installed into special directories, but can instead be unpacked into
>   any directory and still find their own shared libraries.

Thus, in answer to your first question, there's only one value for `$ORIGIN`: `project/run`.

Therefore, the answer to your second question should be to use the following command to link `foo.so`:

```
g++ -shared -o lib/dir/foo.so obj/foo.o -Wl,-soname,foo.so -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib/dir/sub' -Llib/dir/sub -l:bar.so
```

Comment: Please note that (now, at least on some implementations) the first point is not true. If both a program (`main`) and a shared object (`foo`) contain RPATH with the `$ORIGIN` token, and the shared object `foo` loads another shared object `bar`, then during this process of searching for `bar`, first `foo`'s RPATH will be used, with `$ORIGIN` being `foo`'s directory, and only then, if that fails, `main`'s RPATH will be used with `$ORIGIN` being `main`'s directory. Please, see [my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52647116/23715).

Answer (score 5):

First, there are issues with $ sign expansion that might be causing problems. I'm building Python from source and I do this:

```
export LDFLAGS='-Wl,-rpath,\$${ORIGIN}/../lib -Wl,-rpath,\$${ORIGIN}/../usr/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags'
```

before running `make`. That works fine and it finds 1st level dependencies. Be careful with single and double quotes when dealing with this type of macro expansion issue.

Secondly, if you run `objdump -x` on a binary or a library, you can see the RPATH header that it actually contains. When I run `objdump -x path/to/python |grep RPATH` it shows me this.RPATH                ${ORIGIN}/../lib:${ORIGIN}/../usr/lib`

I suggest that you check your binaries to see what is actually in the RPATH header. Unfortunately, I don't think that this will solve your problem. This is what I see when I run `ldd path/to/python`:

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /data1/python27/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00002ad369d4f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002ad36a12f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00002ad36a34d000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x00002ad36a551000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00002ad36a754000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00002ad36a9d8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002ad369b2d000)
```

As you can see, the first level dependency is correctly handled by `rpath` but the second level dependencies, i.e. the dependencies of libpython, revert to system libraries. And yes, libpython has the exact same RPATH header in its binary. I found your question while googling `rpath recursive` to try and resolve my problem of making a distro independent package.

**Added later**
The `rpath` headers only change the FIRST path searched for libraries. If they are not found there, then the loader continues to search in the normal places. `ldd` only lists the actual path of the library that was found as a result of the search. When I copied these libraries to the `rpath` directory, then everything worked. Basically there is no tidy way to find all the dependencies and copy them, just `ldd -v path/to/python` and some parsing of that output.

Comment: This escaping strategy works perfectly. In a similar but unrelated build, I was having trouble getting the `$ORIGIN` text to survive a `configure` script and `make`. Problem solved.

Comment: Why not use`$$ORIGIN` instead?

Comment: I worked on a similar project, and I confirm that single-quoted double-dollar `'$$ORIGIN'` seems to be necessary in order to survive autoconf. Ultimately I used: `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,'\$\$ORIGIN'" ./configure`

Answer (score 3):

Check [my modified version of your make script](https://github.com/zym1010/til/blob/master/Linux/compiler/project/make-correct.sh). Basically, an additional `-rpath-link` without `$ORIGIN` should be used, since `ld` doesn't understand `$ORIGIN` at all.

As for your questions.

1. `$ORIGIN` only works during runtime, and it's w.r.t. each library. So different shared libraries have different `$ORIGIN`.
2. I'm afraid the best way is to add `rpath-link`, and this won't affect your portability, since they are relative, and won't exist in the final executable, as I have shown in my version of `make.sh`

Also, [this is my own understanding of the whole linking stuff](https://github.com/zym1010/til/blob/master/Linux/compiler/linking.md). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this as well, and as best I can tell you need to use `-rpath-link` for any path that would use ORIGIN expansion.  For example:

```
CC -shared (other flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -o /buildpath/lib/libmylib1.so
CC -shared (other flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -lmylib1 -o /buildpath/lib/libmylib2.so
# This fails to link 'somebinary'
CC (various flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -lmylib2 -o /buildpath/bin/somebinary
# This works correctly
CC (various flags) -R'$ORIGIN/../lib/' -Wl,-rpath-link,/buildpath/lib/mylib1 -lmylib2 -o /buildpath/bin/somebinary
# The text above the carets to the right is a typo: ------------------^^^^^^
# I'm fairly sure it should read like this (though it has been awhile since I wrote this):
# (...) -Wl,-rpath-link,/buildpath/lib -lmylib1 (...)
```

`ld` will not expand `$ORIGIN` within paths specified using `-rpath-link` or paths it retrieves from a sub-dependency's RPATH.  In the above example, `mylib2` depends on `mylib1`; while linking `somebinary`, `ld` attempts to find `mylib1` using the literal/unexpanded string `$ORIGIN/../lib/` embedded in libmylib2.so.  `ld.so` would at runtime, but not `ld`.

It also won't use paths specified with `-L` to find the sub-dependency librar(y|ies).

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding this is an issue in ld (i.e. binutils) and how it resolve "Secondary Dependencies"

AFAIK started from `binutils >= 2.30`. rpath in dependencies are added to the search.
i.e. `ld ... main.exe` find `foo.so`, then read the RPATH in `foo.so` thus find `bar.so`

Here my stack overflow question:
[Binutils Secondary Dependency Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647141/binutils-secondary-dependency-change)

And here my investigation on various distro (inside docker container) to test various binutils version
https://github.com/Mizux/SecondaryDependency

note: take a look a the travis-CI log...