# Can I avoid exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH by hardcoding library paths in the executable?

Tags: linux, elf

I'm zipping a *pre-built* (no source/object files) binary application for distribution. The binary application requires a couple of libraries not included by default. The only way I seem to be able to get the application to start on the end-user is by including a `run.sh` that sets the library path to the current directory:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./MyApp.out
```

However, I'd really like to allow the user to just unzip the zip and doubleclick `MyApp.out` (without the shell script). Can I edit `MyApp.out` to search the current directory for the library? I've done something similar on OSX using `install_name_tool`, but that tool isn't available here.

Answer (score 4):

You want to set the [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562437/841108). So link using

```
   gcc yourobjects*.o -L/some/lib/dir/ -lsome -Wl,-rpath,.
```

But you might want even to use `-Wl,-rpath,$PWD` or perhaps `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348353/841108).

You could also (and this should work for a pre-built executable) configure your `/etc/ld.so.conf` by adding a line there with an absolute path (of the directory containing the lib), then running `ldconfig -v` ... See [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)

I would suggest adding `/usr/local/lib` into `/etc/ld.so.conf` and making a symlink from `/usr/local/lib/libfoo.so` to e.g. `$HOME/libfoo.so` etc... (then run `ldconfig`  ...). I don't think adding a user specific directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf` is reasonable ...

PS. What you really want is to [package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28package_management_system%29) your application (e.g. as a `*.deb` package for Debian or Ubuntu, or an `*.rpm` for Fedora or Redhat). Package management systems handle dependencies!

Comment: It's *pre-built*; like, post compile&linker. I can't use `gcc` here. :(