# the shared library RPATH and the binary RPATH priority

Tags: c++, linux, build, rpath

if a shared library is linked to a binary, and the shared library also depends on other libs , what are the priorities (linker search order) of the RPATH of the shared library and the RPATH of the binary ? Could the RPATH of the binary override the one in the shared library?  and the $ORIGIN I set in the shared library RPATH refers to the lib location or the binary location?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

According to my observation, if there is an application `main` which dynamically loads library `first.so`, and the latter in turn dynamically loads library `second.so`, and both `main` and `first.so` contain RPATH, then dynamic linker will search `second.so` first using the `first.so`'s RPATH, resolving $ORIGIN as the `first.so`'s directory, and only if it fails, the linker will proceed to the `main`'s RPATH now resolving $ORIGIN as `main`'s directory.

This does not contradict the [dynamic linker doc (look for Rpath token expansion)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

> $ORIGIN (or equivalently ${ORIGIN}): This expands to the directory containing the program **or shared object**. ...

To check this I've created a test application and two libraries: `main`, `liba` and `libb` respectively. `main` is linked against `liba`, and `liba` is linked against `libb`:

```
main -> liba.so -> libb.so
```

The built binaries are located this way:

```
/cwd/main
/cwd/lib/liba.so
/cwd/lib/libb.so
```

Both `main` and `liba` are built with the `--rpath=\$ORIGIN/lib` linker flag:

```
~$ readelf -a /cwd/main | grep ORIGIN
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/lib]
~$ readelf -a /cwd/lib/liba.so | grep ORIGIN
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/lib]
```

With the help of the [`LD_DEBUG` environment variable](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html#ENVIRONMENT) I've checked how dynamic linker processes RPATH:

```
~$ LD_DEBUG=libs /cwd/main
:     find library=liba.so [0]; searching
:      search path=/cwd/lib/tls/x86_64:/cwd/lib/tls:/cwd/lib/x86_64:/cwd/lib              (RPATH from file /cwd/main)
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/tls/x86_64/liba.so
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/tls/liba.so
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/x86_64/liba.so
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/liba.so
94313:
:     find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
:      search path=/cwd/lib                (RPATH from file /cwd/main)
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/libc.so.6
:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
94313:
:     find library=libb.so [0]; searching
:      search path=/cwd/lib/lib/tls/x86_64:/cwd/lib/lib/tls:/cwd/lib/lib/x86_64:/cwd/lib/lib              (RPATH from file /cwd/lib/liba.so)
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/lib/tls/x86_64/libb.so
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/lib/tls/libb.so
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/lib/x86_64/libb.so
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/lib/libb.so
:      search path=/cwd/lib                (RPATH from file /cwd/main)
:       trying file=/cwd/lib/libb.so
```

From that we can see, that the linker first encounters the need to load `liba.so` and uses the `main` binary's RPATH to resolve this. Then it encounters the need to load `libb.so` and it first uses the `liba.so` library's RPATH to resolve this. But since the RPATH is `$ORIGIN/lib` and `libb.so` is in the same directory as `liba.so`, the linker fails to find `libb.so` using `liba.so`'s RPATH. After that it falls back to `main`'s RPATH and only using the latter it succeeds to find `libb.so`.

Test environment: Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-34-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu (64-bit), /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so.