# CMAKE RPATH with packaging

Tags: cmake, rpath

I am creating package using cmake

I am having following structure

```
bin/
    bin1
lib/

    lib1
    lib2
```

Where lib1 and lib2 are external dynamic library. How can I set RPATH so it will automatically link with lib1 and lib2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been fussing with cmake on this as well.  Cmake uses CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH for linking at build time and CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH to set the rpath used when the install target is built.  cmake has some good info on using its rpath mechanism:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling

An alternative method is to use ldconfig.  I notice that when you build svn(1.6.17), it's make install target invokes ldconfig to set rpath.

take a look at $ORIGIN as you'll need that in your rpath to keep it relative to the binary rather than relative to $PWD.

[Building a simple (hello-world-esque) example of using ld's option -rpath with $ORIGIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311016/building-a-simple-hello-world-esque-example-of-using-lds-option-rpath-with)

Comment: Is there a difference between `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` and `INSTALL_RPATH`?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, CMake automatically adds rpaths to all targets, which you are linking with target_link_libraries().

To switch it off there is `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` option.

Comment: I don't want to switch it off. I am creating an tar archive. and shipping lib1 and lib2 using custom installed command form cmake. I want to RPATH to be linked relatively to the library.

Comment: Ah, i see. Well, i'm even not sure if it's possible to change rpaths on install step, not the build step. By looking at various apps for *NIX that are being distributed in binary form, i can suggest wrapping your executable into shellscript, which would set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running app.

Comment: to 'update' the RPATH you can use https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf which is used for proprietary software and open source as well.